# RewriteRule : replace hyphens with plus signs

Tags: string, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, replace

I just moved my website to a new permalink structure and need to do the following for some URLs.

I'd like to take the final "slug" after the number in
`/Annuaire-Artisan-106-creation-complete-de-salle-de-bains.htm`

Replace hyphens to plus signs, and redirect to `/travaux/new+slug+with+plus+signs` without the final .htm.

...So

```
/Annuaire-Artisan-106-creation-complete-de-salle-de-bains.htm
```

becomes

```
/travaux/creation+complete+de+salle+de+bains
```

I currently have :

```
RewriteRule ^Annuaire-Artisan-([0-9]+)-(.*)-(.*).htm$ /Annuaire-Artisan-$1-$2+$3.htm [L,R,NE]
```

... that correctly transform the hyphens in the last part to plus signs :

```
/Annuaire-Artisan-106-creation+complete+de+salle+de+bains.htm
```

But I can't find the second RewriteRule to ignore the initial `Annuaire-Artisan-106-`and final `.htm` and rewrite to `/travaux/creation+complete+de+salle+de+bains`

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: you can ignore (remove) it in the replacing string of given rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't use the [`R|redirect`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag at this stage, because the client will issue a new request for each hyphen replaced. This is also true for search engines, which might be bad for ranking. Rather use the `L` flag alone, or maybe [`N|next`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) giving

```
RewriteRule ^(Annuaire-Artisan-[0-9]+)-(.*)-(.*)\.htm$ /$1-$2+$3.htm [N=100,NE]
```

`N=100` restricts the loop to at most 100 hyphens. You may adjust this to less, if you like.

The following rule would then remove `.htm` and replace the leading part. It takes a similar pattern and now, it will redirect the client to the new URL

```
RewriteRule ^Annuaire-Artisan-[0-9]+-(.*)\.htm$ /travaux/$1 [R,L,NE]
```

---

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` ([permanent redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)). *Never* test with [`R=301`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542).